# get date from today to weekend

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

i have one datepicker function and there small code:-

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
    var dat = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', new Date());
    $('#date').append(dat);
})
```

this is html:-

```
<div> <ul> <li>This Weekend</li></ul></div>
<p id="date"> 
</p>
```

my try demo jsfiddle  : - http://jsfiddle.net/pMmKc/1/
here i am try to click on `li` `This weekend` then i want to get all date from today to weekend. 
i don't know how to its work.
please somebody help me out with this.
thanks.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you'd like to happen?  I'm confused about exactly what you want to occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TRy

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
    var date = new Date();
    var day = date.getDay();
    while(day < 7){
        $('#date').append($.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', date));
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
        day++;
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4n9Hw/)

Comment: This will include Saturday's date as well.

Comment: then instead of `day < 7` use `day < 6`

Comment: @JackPhp what do you mean by next weekend?

Comment: this weekend end 2013/04/05 then start new weekend 2013/04/06 to  2013/04/12 date

Comment: if you click on the button again do you want to show dates till next weekend